# Problems replacing a key in a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace the value of a nested dictionary with a for loop and if statement, it kinda works but it replaces other keys as well. I tried solutions from other similar problems but no luck. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
d = {'Item 1': {'Name': 'Wireless Power Bank',
                          'Price': '$50',
                          'Status': 'sold-out'},
               'Item 2': {'Name': 'Case - iPhone 12',
                          'Price': '$50',
                          'Status': 'not'},
               'Item 3': {'Name': 'The Case - iPhone 12',
                          'Price': '$50',
                          'Status': 'not'},
               'Item 4': {'Name': 'Case - iPhone 11',
                          'Price': '$50',
                          'Status': 'sold-out'},
               'Item 5': {'Name': 'The Card Case - iPhone X/XS',
                          'Price': '$50',
                          'Status': 'not'}}

        for k, v in d.items():
            for inK, inV in v.items():
                if "sold-out" in inV:
                    d[k][inK] = 'Out of Stock'
                else:
                    d[k][inK] = 'In Stock'
```

Output:

```
{'Item 1': {'Name': 'In Stock', 'Price': 'In Stock', 'Status': 'Out of Stock'},
 'Item 2': {'Name': 'In Stock', 'Price': 'In Stock', 'Status': 'In Stock'},
 'Item 3': {'Name': 'In Stock', 'Price': 'In Stock', 'Status': 'In Stock'},
 'Item 4': {'Name': 'In Stock', 'Price': 'In Stock', 'Status': 'Out of Stock'},
 'Item 5': {'Name': 'In Stock', 'Price': 'In Stock', 'Status': 'In Stock'}}
```

Expected Output:

```
              {'Item 1': {'Name': 'Wireless Power Bank',
                          'Price': '$50',
                          'Status': 'Out of Stock'},
               'Item 2': {'Name': 'Case - iPhone 12',
                          'Price': '$50',
                          'Status': 'In Stock'},
               'Item 3': {'Name': 'The Case - iPhone 12',
                          'Price': '$50',
                          'Status': 'In Stock'},
               'Item 4': {'Name': 'Case - iPhone 11',
                          'Price': '$50',
                          'Status': 'Out of Stock'},
               'Item 5': {'Name': 'The Card Case - iPhone X/XS',
                          'Price': '$50',
                          'Status': 'In Stock'}}
```

Comment: Drop the inner loop and just check if the string appears within d[k]["Status"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved thanks to @luk2302!

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if "sold-out" in d[k]["Status"]:
        d[k]["Status"] = 'Out of Stock'
    else:
        d[k]["Status"] = 'In Stock'
```

Output:

```
{'Item 1': {'Name': 'Wireless Power Bank', 'Price': '$50', 'Status': 'Out of Stock'},
 'Item 2': {'Name': 'Case - iPhone 12', 'Price': '$50', 'Status': 'In Stock'},
 'Item 3': {'Name': 'The Case - iPhone 12', 'Price': '$50', 'Status': 'In Stock'},
 'Item 4': {'Name': 'Case - iPhone 11', 'Price': '$50', 'Status': 'Out of Stock'},
 'Item 5': {'Name': 'The Card Case - iPhone X/XS', 'Price': '$50', 'Status': 'In Stock'}}
```